# keepalived - How do you define multilpe VRRP instances on same interface?

Tags: rhel7, keepalived

I am in a situation where I need to set 2 VRRP instances on same interface. I need to achieve this because **rsyslogd** and **elasticsearch** needs to use interface *eth0* for network communication.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623214/keepalived-multiple-vrrp-instances-vs-1-instance-with-multiple-vips) post seemed to be a similar one did not mention about the configuration so I decided to ask a question.

I created a configuration below but two masters are created on different host.

### Master side configuration

```
vrrp_script chk_rsyslog {
  script "netstat -atunp | grep rsyslogd | grep '0.0.0.0:514' &>/dev/null"
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
}

vrrp_script chk_es {
  script "netstat -atunp | grep java | grep '192.168.21.14:9300' &>/dev/null"
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK

vrrp_instance RH_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 50
    priority 10
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.11.250/24
    }

    track_script {
      chk_rsyslog
    }
}

vrrp_instance ES_1 {
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 10
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.11.251/24
    }

    track_script {
      chk_es
    }
}
```

### Backup side configuration

```
vrrp_script chk_rsyslog {
  script "netstat -atunp | grep rsyslogd | grep '0.0.0.0:514' &>/dev/null"
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
}

vrrp_script chk_es {
  script "netstat -atunp | grep java | grep '192.168.21.15:9300' &>/dev/null"
  interval 2 # every 2 seconds
  weight 2 # add 2 points if OK
}

vrrp_instance RH_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 50
    priority 9
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.11.250/24
    }

    track_script {
      chk_rsyslog
    }
}

vrrp_instance ES_1 {
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 9
    advert_int 1
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.11.251/24
    }

    track_script {
      chk_es
    }
}
```

Log on the backup side shows both instances first starts up but ES_1 is not reflected to ip setting for os.

```
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Netlink reflector reports IP 192.168.11.15 added
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Netlink reflector reports IP 192.168.21.15 added
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Netlink reflector reports IP fe80::ab04:d4e4:841e:e3e1 added
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Netlink reflector reports IP fe80::812:1dd8:9ed1:a6af added
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Configuration is using : 69267 Bytes
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: VRRP_Instance(RH_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: VRRP_Instance(ES_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(2), proto(112), unicast(0), fd(10,11)]
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_healthcheckers[23320]: Configuration is using : 7722 Bytes
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_healthcheckers[23320]: Using LinkWatch kernel netlink reflector...
Apr 19 08:49:54 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: VRRP_Script(chk_rsyslog) succeeded
Apr 19 08:49:58 rhel2 Keepalived_vrrp[23321]: VRRP_Instance(RH_1) Transition to MASTER STATE
```

My ip addr command result.

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:12:0e:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.11.15/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.11.250/24 scope global secondary eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ab04:d4e4:841e:e3e1/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Is it possible to set multiple VRRP instances on same interface?

My platform information is below.

```
[root@rhel2 keepalived]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
[root@rhel2 keepalived]# rpm -qa | grep keepalived
keepalived-1.2.13-8.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not have closing bracket '}' for chk_es